# How to extend clock() execution time

Tags: c, linux

My C program can run more than 3 hours. For the sake of my experiment, I want to calculate the duration time (i.e., execution time) taken by the program until it finishes. I use `start = clock();` at the beginning of `main()`, at the end I do `end = clock()`, finally subtract `end - start` the get the execution time. However, as it is said [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm), `clock_t clock(void)` is limited to 72 minutes. How can I enforce it to count the whole execution time not only 72 minutes?

Comment: Don't use obscure sites as reference. There is no guarantee in the standard for a specific max. duration.

Comment: There are many cool functions in `time.h`. Why not to take a look?

Comment: What's your target?  Linux, windows, C99, other?  How much resolution do you need (second, sub-second, sub-tick)?

Comment: @BrianCain I am targeting Linux, and would like to calculate in terms of hours and minutes.

Comment: Realize also that `clock()` returns the CPU time spent by the program, not the wall clock time. It's not clear to me which one you're interested in.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I want to get the duration time from the time that the program runs until the end. Just how long does it take in simple way

Comment: If your program runs for several hours would one second accuracy be good? If so, you can use the simple `time` function to stamp the beginning and end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function is specified in C89, C99, C11.  It has second resolution and usually spans more than 30-bits worth of seconds.  It's likely the most portable solution.  In fact, I'd never heard of `clock()` until today.  Counting ticks is rarely what you want even if you need high resolution.</strike>

If you don't need a portable way to measure CPU/execution time, use [`procfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).  `proc/self/stat`'s `stime` field and `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` should be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `gettimeofday()` (https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday). It offers microsecond resolution over a very long period. Record the start time and the end time and calculate the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The standard across all POSIXy systems, including, Linux, is the [clock_gettime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) POSIX.1 function.

Consider the following example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Clock used by wall_start()/wall_elapsed() */
#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#define  WALL_CLOCK_ID  CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#else
#define  WALL_CLOCK_ID  CLOCK_REALTIME
#endif

static struct timespec  wall_started = { 0 };

static inline void wall_start(void)
{
    if (clock_gettime(WALL_CLOCK_ID, &wall_started)) {
        wall_started.tv_sec = 0;
        wall_started.tv_nsec = 0;
    }
}

static inline void wall_elapsed(void)
{
    struct timespec  t;
    if (!clock_gettime(WALL_CLOCK_ID, &t))
        return (double)(t.tv_sec - wall_started.tv_sec)
             + (double)(t.tv_nsec - wall_started.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    else
        return -1.0;
}

/* Return the number of seconds of CPU time
   used by this process (includes all threads)
*/
static inline double cpu_elapsed(void)
{
    struct timespec  t;

    if (!clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t))
        return (double)t.tv_sec
             + (double)t.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;

    return -1.0;
}
```

If you want to display the time in days, hours, minutes, and seconds, you'll also need a simple function to split the (floating-point) seconds into days, hours, and minutes.

Here is one implementation, which takes pointers to ints for days, hours, and minutes; you can use NULL if you don't want to split that out. The function returns the remaining seconds:

```
static inline double split_seconds(double  secs,
                                   int    *days,
                                   int    *hours,
                                   int    *minutes)
{
    /* We split the absolute number of seconds, only. */
    if (secs < 0.0)
        secs = 0.0;

    if (days) {
        const int  ndays = (int)(secs / 86400.0);
        secs -= (double)ndays * 86400.0;
        *days = ndays;
    }

    if (hours) {
        const int  nhours = (int)(secs / 3600.0);
        secs -= (double)nhours * 3600.0;
        *hours = nhours;
    }

    if (minutes) {
        const int  nminutes = (int)(secs / 60.0);
        secs -= (double)nminutes * 60.0;
        *minutes = nminutes;
    }

    return secs;
}
```

For example, calling `split_seconds(3661.25, NULL, &h, NULL)` returns `61.25` with `h == 1`. Calling `split_seconds(3661.25, &d, &h, &m)` returns `1.25`, with `d == 0`, `h == 1`, `m == 1`, corresponding to 0 days, 1 hour, 1 minute, and 1.25 seconds.

The `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock is the standard wall clock in POSIXy systems, but it is affected by NTP (Network Time Protocol) changes, and the system administrator can directly set it. It is not, however, affected by Daylight Savings Time or anything related to timezones, because it is in UTC, not local time.

The `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock is similar to `CLOCK_REALTIME`, except that its epoch is unknown (probably set to some time in the past when the machine last booted), and it is not affected by NTP time jumps (but is affected by small incremental changes by NTP, to keep the computer clock synchronized to network time sources), and is not affected by system time changes by the system administrator.

If available, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is considered better for measuring elapsed real-world time than `CLOCK_REALTIME`; `CLOCK_REALTIME` is better suited to cases where you compare to an absolute real-world time, or check if a specific date/time has already passed or not.

If you intend to store a timestamp to e.g. a file, you must use `CLOCK_REALTIME` and not `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, because the latter is only meaningful on that same machine, and only until the next boot.

When using `CLOCK_REALTIME`, remember that it is in UTC, and users normally specify their times and dates in local time; you probably want to use [`strptime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) POSIX.1 function to parse the text (use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` in Linux), and [`mktime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) to generate the `time_t` you can store to the `tv_sec` member of a `struct timespec` structure.